# Is it guaranteed that kubernetes delete pending firstly while scaling in?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm doing kubernetes scaling manually by running `kubectl scale --replica`. I'd like to confirm if kubernetes choose pending pod firstly instead of running pod when the given replicas is smaller than the current replica number.

For example, the current status in cluster is:

```
example-fm1uw   1/1       Running   0          1h
example-2wy75   1/1       Running   0          1h 
example-dtvlh   1/1       pending   0          1h
```

If I run `kubectl scale --replicas=2 -f example.yaml`, which node would be choose to delete first? Is `example-dtvlh` chosen to delete first?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. There is an order for kubernetes preference to delete pods.

> Sort the pods in the order such that not-ready < ready,
>   unscheduled < scheduled, and pending < running. This ensures
>   that we delete pods in the earlier stages whenever possible.

[kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.3/pkg/controller/replication/replication_controller.go#L504)